# I need help on scripting making input to direct argument

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
!/bin/bash
```

codes remove for safety thanks for the ones who help

Hi I need help on this I made this code it is used to view the file owner and the file size in kb.

Example of process:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./a.sh 

Desktop/ubiquity-gtkui.desktop 

Owner: ubuntu

Size: 8.6K
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./a.sh   Desktop/ubiquity-gtkui.desktop 

Owner: ubuntu

Size: 8.6K
```

The first example is an input type I need is the argument type that needs to be:

```
./file.sh [path to file home/usr/file.txt]
```

not like:

```
./file.sh 

[path to file home/usr/file.txt]
```

Thanks you all

Comment: please i need help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "" FILEPATH
FILE=$FILEPATH
```

with

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=${1?No path specified}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?  The first argument you specify on the command line is available inside the script as `$1`

Comment: ok sir thanks there was a little error on what i typed silly me its ok now thank you verymuch